# Express controller code doesn't seem to be running asynchronously

Tags: node.js, express, async-await

This is a much simplified version of an ExpressJS controller I have.

I put the sleep function in to test loading indicators on my front-end and I was very surprised that when calling this function twice simultaneously from the browser, instead of both taking 5 seconds they took a total of 10 seconds to complete.

```
function sleep(ms: number) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms))
}


const get =  async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {

    await sleep(5000)

    res.status(200).json({})


}

export default get
```

[image]

My understanding was that because I am using all asynchronous code the first one would wait for the timeout while other requests to the server continue to be served.

Whilst I don't use a sleep function everywhere else I do have lots of async code and I'm worried that each time I make a long DB call my API is being stopped from serving other requests, but this doesn't fit with my understanding of how Node/Express works, so am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: How are you calling this in the frontend?

Comment: React front end with a simple component used twice on the page. The component uses axios.get() to make the request but I can confirm that the requests are starting at the same time, not delayed.

Comment: See further explanation here: [Nodejs handling multiple requests at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66606877/node-js-server-handling-multiple-requests-at-same-time/66608460#66608460).  This explains what the browser is doing here and how you can defeat it by adding a simple random query string parameter or setting a config option for `fetch()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a client-side issue with the browser caching.

I set up a test server based on your sample (side note, always helpful to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)...makes it quicker and easier for others to troubleshoot/reproduce your problem)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

app.get('/tst', async (req, res, next) => {
  await sleep(5000);
  res.status(200).json({});
  res.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

When I tried two fetches, I saw the same thing as you, they appear to run in serial: one finished in 5s, the other in 10s.

But then when I disabled the browser cache, they ran in parallel, both finishing at the exact same time:

```
fetch('/tst', {cache:'no-store'});
fetch('/tst', {cache:'no-store'});
```

In a "real world" environment this probably won't matter much, since you're probably more concerned about different users. In that case it won't matter, since they're not sharing a cache.

Comment: Wow, that absolutely worked. Not sure what the Chrome cache is doing but I was starting to reconsider everything I knew about Noe and Express. Can't thank you enough.

Comment: Yeah browser caching is a huge pain...I've fought with it many times. Your screenshot shows 200 responses, but I noticed that I was getting 304 (not modified) responses, which made me think it was the cache. Also, I just tested in firefox and it doesn't have this behavior. Not sure about other browsers like opera or safari...might just be chromium-based browsers.